# Derive formula from output coefficients

Tags: r, machine-learning, generalized-linear-model

How do I derive a binary logistic formula from my generalised linear model?
[image]

Is it Y = 0.94806 + 0.49821*x1 + 0.18483*x2 + 0.50868*x3 + 1.07113*x4 - 1.58963*x5 -0.56045*x6 + 0.92653*x7 - 0.02139*x8 - 0.43157*x9 + 0.14469*x10 ?

How does that work with the intercept being 0.94806? I'm concerned by the fact that it would take very little to exceed 1, which I assume is what gives a positive outcome Y?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's

$$ P(Y | X) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(0.95 + 0.50 x_1 + 0.18 x_2 + 0.51 x_3 + 1.07 x_4 - 1.59 x_5 -0.56 x_6 + 0.93 x_7 - 0.02 x_8 - 0.43 x_9 + 0.14 x_{10})}} $$